# Filtrado multiple Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, postgresql, djangorestframework

Quería hacer un filtrado múltiple por URL con la API **Django Rest Framework** es decir que por ejemplo escriba: `www.domain.com/clientes/Nike/ES`

Y me devuelva todos clientes de Nike de España, la cosa es que no sé como cruzar las tablas, ahora mismo he logrado filtrar por id: `www.domain.com/clientes/1/`

La cosa es que Nike no es la id de su tabla y ES tampoco es la id de su tabla, y no sé como filtrar por diferentes campos que no sean la id y cruzar tablas para devolver el JSON con los campos que me interesa, no hace falta me anide toda la marca sino que me devuelva su nombre o el campo deseado en concreto.

Archivo `api/views.py`:

```
class ClienteViewset(ModelViewSet):
      serializer_class = ClienteSerializer
      queryset = ClienteModel.object.all()
      lookup_field = 'cliente_id'

cliente_list = ClienteViewset.as_view({'get': 'list'})
cliente_detail = ClienteViewset.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})
```

Archivo `api/urls.py`:

```
router.register(r'clientes', ClienteViewset)

urlpatterns = patterns('api.views',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls))
)
```

Archivo `serializers.py`:

```
class ClienteSerializer(ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Cliente
         fields = ('cliente_id', 'cliente_nombre', 'cliente_apellidos')
```

Si alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo me sería de gran ayuda aunque sea con los objetos anidados dentro del JSON.

La cosa es que tengo una base de datos bastante compleja en tema de relaciones, ya que tengo textos por idiomas, marcas, etc....

Answer (score 4):

¿Por qué no usas los filtros genéricos que provee DRF a través de DjangoFilterBackend?

Aquí en la [documentación](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) lo mencionan.
Solo tienes que instalar `django-filter` y la clase `DjangoFilterBackend` como un filter backend, seria algo asi:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class ClienteViewset(ModelViewSet):
      serializer_class = ClienteSerializer
      queryset = ClienteModel.object.all()
      filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
      filter_fields = ('cliente_nombre', 'paises__codigo')
```

y luego el filtro seria asi:
`www.domain.com/clientes/?cliente_nombre=Nike&paises__codigo=ES`

Por otro lado, si realmente quieres filtrar valores en las urls `/{param1}/{param2}/` en lugar de parámetros `?param1=val1&param2=val2` puedes instalar [nested-routes](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) que te facilita hacer eso.